# Hide vision of image temporarily in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

I'm going to enable bloody screen when got attack then disble it for two seconds.

The first way I tried is using `SetActive (true/flase)` .

It could work once but never worked back anymore.

I found the question by google, it seems that function will disable everything of that component.

So I found the second way which is using `Image Class` to do this.

but I not sure whether the way I used correctly or not.

The error msg : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

> First Way (working once)

```
public class GameControllerScript : MonoBehaviour { 

public GameObject bloodyScreen; 

void Start () { 
    bloodyScreen.gameObject.SetActive (false);  // disable at first
} 

void Update () { 

} 

public void zombieAttack(bool zombieIsThere ){ 

    bloodyScreen.gameObject.SetActive (true); 
    StartCoroutine(WaitTwoSeconds()); 
} 

IEnumerator WaitTwoSeconds(){ 

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (2f);
    bloodyScreen.gameObject.SetActive (false); 
} }
```

> Second Way  (not working)

```
public class GameControllerScript : MonoBehaviour { 

    public Image image;

    void Start () { 
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
        if (!go)
            return;
        image = go.GetComponent<Image>();
        image.enable = false;

    } 

    void Update () { 

    } 

    public void zombieAttack(bool zombieIsThere ){ 

        image.enabled = true;
        StartCoroutine(WaitTwoSeconds()); 
    } 

    IEnumerator WaitTwoSeconds(){ 

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2f);
        image.enabled = false;
    } }
```

Sorry for my english if soemthing is not clear.

> What my object likes https://i.stack.imgur.com/DChuS.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are so many ways of doing the **BLOODY SCREEN**.

1.)

STEP 1

Make an array of texture then put all of your texture there

STEP 2

On your `OnTriggerEnter` or `OnCollisionEnter` or what ever function you want and try implementing this code

```
Texture[] arrayOfTexture = new Texture

 foreach(Texture textures in arrayOfTexture){
    //set the alpha here from 1-0/0-1
 }
```

2.)

You can do it also in an `Update()` function and put it on a timer you can do it something like

```
float timer = 10f;

void Update(){
   timer -= time.DeltaTime;
   if(timer < 1){
      //reset timer here

   }else{
      //do the alpha thing here
   }
}

 void ResetTimer(){
    timer = 10f;
 }
```